# merging two date columns on hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different data

weather:

```
    time                dayweather
0   2015-11-14 01:00:00   Clouds
1   2015-11-14 03:00:00   Clouds
2   2015-11-14 05:00:00   Clouds
3   2015-11-14 06:00:00   Clouds
4   2015-11-14 08:00:00   Clouds
```

speed:

```
    id            time                  machine_id    speed_gps_kph  latitude     longitude
0   14641931007   2015-11-15 17:46:40         10051         3       -36.725578    174.71482
1   14642568129   2015-11-15 18:12:41         10051        13       -36.769465    174.74159
2   14641876524   2015-11-15 17:44:30         10051        0        -36.723136    174.714432
3   14642262476   2015-11-15 18:00:47         10051        17       -36.747435    174.723397
4   14641991113   2015-11-15 17:49:43         10051        6        -36.72826     174.715083
```

I need to merge this two data on time then check how weather affect data. So I merge the two data

```
dfs = [dataframe,weather]
checkweather = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='left',on='time'), dfs)
```

but my problem is as you can see the dayweather data seems only exactly the same time.

[image]

[image]

so How can I make if speed data time is between 2 hours(some weather time is recorded every hour) in the weather data time show dayweather result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (dataframe)
                 time dayweather
0 2015-11-14 01:00:00    Clouds1
1 2015-11-14 03:00:00    Clouds2
2 2015-11-14 05:00:00    Clouds3
3 2015-11-14 06:00:00    Clouds4
4 2015-11-14 08:00:00       Rain

print (weather)
            id                time  machine_id  speed_gps_kph   latitude  \
0  14641931007 2015-11-14 04:46:40       10051              3 -36.725578   
1  14642568129 2015-11-14 05:12:41       10051             13 -36.769465   
2  14641876524 2015-11-14 06:44:30       10051              0 -36.723136   
3  14642262476 2015-11-14 07:00:47       10051             17 -36.747435   
4  14641991113 2015-11-15 17:49:43       10051              6 -36.728260   

    longitude  
0  174.714820  
1  174.741590  
2  174.714432  
3  174.723397  
4  174.715083
```

---

```
df = pd.merge_asof(weather, dataframe, on='time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2H'))
print (df)
            id                time  machine_id  speed_gps_kph   latitude  \
0  14641931007 2015-11-14 04:46:40       10051              3 -36.725578   
1  14642568129 2015-11-14 05:12:41       10051             13 -36.769465   
2  14641876524 2015-11-14 06:44:30       10051              0 -36.723136   
3  14642262476 2015-11-14 07:00:47       10051             17 -36.747435   
4  14641991113 2015-11-15 17:49:43       10051              6 -36.728260   

    longitude dayweather  
0  174.714820    Clouds2  
1  174.741590    Clouds3  
2  174.714432    Clouds4  
3  174.723397    Clouds4  
4  174.715083        NaN
```

Another solution is use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) ([`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.first.html) is necesarry because text column) for mapping `Series` and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `time` truncated by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
m = dataframe.set_index('time').resample('H')['dayweather'].first().ffill()
weather['dayweather'] = weather['time'].dt.floor('H').map(m)
print (weather)
            id                time  machine_id  speed_gps_kph   latitude  \
0  14641931007 2015-11-14 04:46:40       10051              3 -36.725578   
1  14642568129 2015-11-14 05:12:41       10051             13 -36.769465   
2  14641876524 2015-11-14 06:44:30       10051              0 -36.723136   
3  14642262476 2015-11-14 07:00:47       10051             17 -36.747435   
4  14641991113 2015-11-15 17:49:43       10051              6 -36.728260   

    longitude dayweather  
0  174.714820    Clouds2  
1  174.741590    Clouds3  
2  174.714432    Clouds4  
3  174.723397    Clouds4  
4  174.715083        NaN
```

Comment: Hey, @jezrael thank you fast answer I have two question one is when I try your second code I have some different result for example in some data only 1 minutes changes but I can see 3 different weather. The second question is your first example is working but some days in data hours changing 1 hour Do I have to change TimeDelta('2H') for each specific days?

Comment: Hard answering without data, but in my opinion the best is check differences. second solution is more transparent, it only add missing hours by resample if missing and then map - `merge_asof` is a bit complicated and maybe if some overlaping data results can be different.

Comment: Or maybe need `weather['time'].dt.round('H')` instead `floor` ?

Comment: You can also check `m` if mapping is OK.

Comment: Maybe you ca nmodify and test sample what I use in my answer  `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'dayweather': ['Clouds1', 'Clouds2', 'Clouds3', 'Clouds4', 'Rain'], 'time': [pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 03:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 05:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 06:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 08:00:00')]})`

Comment: `weather = pd.DataFrame({'machine_id': [10051, 10051, 10051, 10051, 10051], 'longitude': [174.71482, 174.74159, 174.71443200000002, 174.723397, 174.71508300000002], 'time': [pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 04:46:40'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 05:12:41'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 06:44:30'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-14 07:00:47'), pd.Timestamp('2015-11-15 17:49:43')], 'speed_gps_kph': [3, 13, 0, 17, 6], 'id': [14641931007, 14642568129, 14641876524, 14642262476, 14641991113], 'latitude': [-36.725578000000006, -36.769465000000004, -36.723136, -36.747434999999996, -36.72826]})`

Comment: @Axis - best is test solution in small samples and if all OK, apply solution to real data ;)

Comment: You are right second your answer is much better, No nan values and data is all match! Thank you.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice weekend!